# Using Renjin's CEM library inside a java application

Tags: java, data-mining, renjin

As the title suggests, I need to implement Coarsened Exact Matching inside a Java application. I found out that [Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/index.html) embeds this [library](http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/cem) but I cannot figure out how to use it in my Java app, i.e. how to install it, invoke matching methods etc...
Any idea or example? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added tcltk stubs to Renjin today, so with the latest version you can now use the [cem](https://renjinci.appspot.com/package/org.renjin.cran/cem/1.1.17) package.

There are no plans to add true support for Tcl/Tk graphical user interfaces, so any functions from cem that actually rely on tcltk will fail, but all of the actual computation should work.

Comment: That is great. Thanks for the update. I'll definitely take it into account for future works.

Answer (score 1):

Read better:

> This package **cannot yet be used** with Renjin it depends on other packages which are not available: tcltk

The reason is that TCL/TK requires *native* code, which is a pain to use in Java. Because nobody did write that code yet it cannot be used yet.